# Spark Stream new Job after stream start

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, streaming, spark-streaming

I have a situation where I am trying to stream using spark streaming from kafka. The stream is a direct stream. I am able to create a stream and then start streaming, also able to get any updates (if any) on kafka via the streaming.

The issue comes in when i have a new request to stream a new topic. Since SparkStreaming context can be only 1 per jvm, I cannot create a new stream for every new request.

The way I figured out is

1. Once a DStream is created and spark streaming is already in progress, just attach a new stream to it. This does not seem to work, the createDStream (for a new topic2) does not return a stream and further processing is stopped. The streaming keep on continuing on the first request (say topic1).
2. Second, I thought to stop the stream, create DStream and then start streaming again. I cannot use the same streaming context (it throws an excpection that jobs cannot be added after streaming has been stopped), and if I create a new stream for new topic (topic2), the old stream topic (topic1) is lost and it streams only the new one.

Here is the code, have a look

```
 JavaStreamingContext javaStreamingContext;
        if(null == javaStreamingContext) {
            javaStreamingContext =  JavaStreamingContext(sparkContext, Durations.seconds(duration));
        } else {
            StreamingContextState streamingContextState = javaStreamingContext.getState();
            if(streamingContextState == StreamingContextState.STOPPED) {
                javaStreamingContext =  JavaStreamingContext(sparkContext, Durations.seconds(duration));
            }


        }
Collection<String> topics = Arrays.asList(getTopicName(schemaName));
        SparkVoidFunctionImpl impl = new SparkVoidFunctionImpl(getSparkSession());

        KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(javaStreamingContext,
                LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(topics, getKafkaParamMap()))
                .map((stringStringConsumerRecord) -> stringStringConsumerRecord.value())
                .foreachRDD(impl);
if (javaStreamingContext.getState() == StreamingContextState.ACTIVE) {

            javaStreamingContext.start();
            javaStreamingContext.awaitTermination();
        }
```

Don't worry about SparkVoidFunctionImpl, this is a custom class with is the implementation of VoidFunction.

The above is approach 1, where i do not stop the existing streaming. When a new request comes into this method, it does not get a new streaming object, it tries to create a dstream. The issue is the DStream object is never returned.

```
KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(javaStreamingContext,
                    LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                    ConsumerStrategies.<String, String>Subscribe(topics, getKafkaParamMap()))
```

This does not return a dstream, the control just terminates without an error.The steps further are not executed.

I have tried many things and read multiple article, but I belive this is a very common production level issue. Any streaming done is to be done on multiple different topics and each of them is handled differently.

Please help

Comment: is your objective to read multiple topics at once? do they really need to be added/removed dynamically?

Comment: It's not at once, consider them as a rest api request.
So  Time T1, a request comes to stream topic Topic1. I create a dstream and start the streaming.

now at Time T2 > T1, second rest api request comes to stream topic 2,
So the streaming for topic 1 is already in progress and some client is subscribing to it. Some other client wants Topic2 to be streamed.
My options are that to stop streaming and create a dstream for topic2, but then i loose the streaming to topic1.
Second option is to create a dStream without stopping the stream, which does not seem to work

Answer (score 1):

The thing is spark master sends out code to workers and although the data is streaming, underlying code and variable values remain static unless job is restarted.

Few options I could think:

1. Spark Job server: Every time you want to subscribe/stream from a different topic instead of touching already running job, start a new job. From your API body you can supply the parameters or topic name. If you want to stop streaming from a specific topic, just stop respective job. It will give you a lot of flexibility and control on resources.
2. [Theoritical] Topic Filter: Subscribe all topics you think you will want, when records are pulled for a duration, filter out records based on a LIST of topics. Manipulate this list of topics through API to increase or decrease your scope of topics, it could be a broadcast variable as well. This is just an idea, I have not tried this option at all.
3. Another work around is to relay your Topic-2 data to Topic-1 using a microservice whenever you need it & stop if you don't want to.

Comment: I like your first option, but how do I get the running jobs and create a new Job. I have tried starting a new stream(as mentioned), whenever I do that,  the control terminates

Comment: You can check this out
https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver

Comment: i like this idea, will try and implement and update you. Just have a question, I am using KafkaUtils.createDirectStream which returns me a JavaDStream, can we use something like this to relate to a job server? Instead of starting a indivisual stream, attach a spark job server to streaming context?